# Change multiple text in anchor tag on multiple dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 dropdown as bellow

```
<select class="form-control" name="class" id="class">
   <option value="One">One</option>
   <option value="Two">Two</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="section" id="section">
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

and one anchor tag as bellow:

```
<a href="$root_url/**class**/**section**"></a>
```

Now I want to change **class** and **section** text in the anchor tag when use select class and section from dropdown.

For example,
If use select class "One" and section "A" from the dropdown then the class and section text will be replace with "One" and "A"

It will look like `<a href="$root_url/One/A"></a>` after selecting dropdown. I need it to change live. so when I click on the anchor tag then it will redirect me to the link.

Comment: Add an `on change event handler` to drop down with `id = "section"`, in the `callback function`, get your link and set its `href` property appending the selected value from each drop down into a string like const hrefValue = "$root_url/" + dropDown1Value + "/" + dropDown2Value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do, is rebuild the url every time you change one of your selects. The idea is very simple, save each select value in a variable. Then, add a function for each select on `change` event, that will modify it's respective value and rebuild the `href` of your anchor.

The code below does the trick.

```js
var classValue = $('#class').val();
var sectionValue = $('#section').val();
var anchor = $('#target-anchor');

$('#class').on('change', function() {
  classValue = $(this).val();
  buildHref();
})

$('#section').on('change', function() {
  sectionValue = $(this).val();
  buildHref();
})

function buildHref() {
  $(anchor).attr("href", "$root_url/" + classValue + "/" + sectionValue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" name="class" id="class">
   <option value="One">One</option>
   <option value="Two">Two</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="section" id="section">
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

<a id="target-anchor" href="$root_url/**class**/**section**"></a>
```